# Set Bootstrap 4 collapse default hidden or shown based on breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For a Bootstrap 4 target element, I would like it hidden by default up to the XS breakpoint, and shown by default on SM and above.

I know this could be done with JavaScript but was wondering if I was missing a CSS-only solution.

For example:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Link with href</a>

<div class="row">
    <div id="collapse1" class="col-sm-3 collapse">
        Default on XS should be hidden, default on SM+ should be visible
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        Always visible, expands to full row when other column is hidden
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution...

Simply reversing the collapse show class behaviour at a breakpoint does the job.

I've added a collapse-reverse class which reverses the show class behaviour on SM+.

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .collapse.collapse-reverse.show {display:none!important}
    .collapse.collapse-reverse:not(.show) {display:block!important}
}
```

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Link with href</a>

<div class="row">
    <div id="collapse1" class="col-sm-3 collapse collapse-reverse">
        Default on XS should be hidden, default on SM+ should be visible
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        Always visible, expands to full row when other column is hidden
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media-queries to toggle an element on specific viewports:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  #collapse1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #collapse1.show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36xfLyct/

Or for other cases you can use bootstrap display classes `d-none d-sm-block` together on your element to hide or show them.

https://jsfiddle.net/5p9mwqg6/

Bootstrap documentation about display utilities: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: I tested and the d-* classes are overriding show so the collapse target element does not show on XS when the collapse link is pressed, and doesn't hide on SM+ when the button is pressed.

Comment: I checked your edit and it doesn't seem to do what I needed, but it did inspire me to come up with an answer that seems to work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I got what you mean with your answer, check my latest edit. edit: Oh well it's not hidden on xs by default. :D . Interesting logic :)

Comment: I checked the edit. On SM+ the default should be visible. Other than that it is okay.